# Manual for IDE Syquest EZ135

Tags: documentation

Anyone know where I can find a copy of the manual for a IDE Syquest EZ135?  My google-fu yields only the manual for the parallel-port version.

I'm specifically looking for where/how to set the master/slave jumper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling turns up [a manual for some of their DOS utilities](http://www.os2site.com/sw/drivers/storage/i_352_3.txt) which explains:

> This software is designed to support SyQuest IDE drives connected to a generic IDE adapter, a SyQuest SQ08 IDE controller, SyQuest EZ135 PP
>   drives and SyQuest EZFlyer PP drives
>   ...
>
> At the end of this file, there is a short description of the jumpers
>   on the SyQuest internal IDE drive.

So it sounds like this would apply to an IDE EX135. At the end:

> **Master/Slave jumper pins**
>
> This set of jumper pins is on one end of the jumper block and
>   is marked as such.  The drive is a master when a jumper is
>   installed on the pins, slave otherwise.
>
> You can connect one or two IDE drives to an IDE cable.
>   If you have only one drive, it must be Master, if you have
>   two, one must be master and the other must be slave.
>
> System uses the master drive first.  If you already have
>   an IDE drive on the system, you need to find out how to
>   configure it so that it will work with a slave SyQuest
>   Drive.
>
> All other sets must not be jumped.

Sounds pretty standard. Does this match what you see on the drive?